# how to remove None cell from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df,

```
        contents    values  scoresBinned    categories
    0   Buy           484   (375, 500]       Bin 4
    1   Sell          429   (375, 500]       Bin 4
    2   Blanks        130   (125, 250]       Bin 2
    3   A             108   (0, 125]         Bin 1
    4   B             77    (0, 125]         Bin 1
    5   F              2    (0, 125]         Bin 1
```

as I need Bin as my header I am doing df,pivot

```
 filter_df1=df[["contents","categories"]]

 pivot_df=filter_df1.pivot(columns="categories")

 print(pivot_df)

                contents
    categories  Bin 1      Bin 2    Bin 4
       0        None        None    Buy
       1        None        None    Sell
       2        None        Blanks  None
       3        A           None    None
       4        B           None    None
       5        F           None    None
```

I tried df.dropna() but it deletes entire row,

My desired df is,

```
            Bin 1      Bin 2    Bin 4
             A         Blanks   Buy
             B                  Sell
             F
```

Comment: how are you outputting your dataframe?

Comment: Your desired dataframe makes no sense. Removing a single 'cell' from a dataframe makes no sense. Your desired output puts values into rows they weren't previously in, i.e. it completely jumbles the data and returns something which makes no sense..

Comment: I edited my question, please check

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @greg_data: this happens in real life. For example, it happened to me recently when I did a column bind on multiple dataframes that had all the same column names, but all columns in all dataframes had different length. Reports can be like that sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted`, `boolean indexing` and `fillna` to do that.

```
pm = pivot_df.apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull)
new = pm[~pd.isnull(pm).all(1)].fillna('')
```

Output :

```
           contents              
categories    Bin 1   Bin 2 Bin 4
0                 A  Blanks   Buy
1                 B          Sell
2                 F
```

**Explanation** :

Sorting based on None will give

```
           contents              
categories    Bin 1   Bin 2 Bin 4
0                 A  Blanks   Buy
1                 B    None  Sell
2                 F    None  None
3              None    None  None
4              None    None  None
5              None    None  None
```

Now select those rows where the all the values in a row is not null. So we can use `~pd.isnull(pm).all(1)`(Here `~` is not operator which will covert false to true and vise versa).  Which will give

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Later boolen indexing to select the data i.e `pm[~pd.isnull(pm).all(1)]`

```
        contents              
categories    Bin 1   Bin 2 Bin 4
0                 A  Blanks   Buy
1                 B    None  Sell
2                 F    None  None
```

`fillna('')` will fill the none values with `''`. Hope it helps.

Comment: it worked, can you explain this line, new = pm[~pd.isnull(pm).all(1)].fillna('')